# Git Sparse Checkout Fails on Some Directories but Not Others

Tags: git

I have a sparse checkout file that works when I put in some directories for my repo but doesn't work for others.  When I try to add the directory data files by making the contents of sparse-checkout as follows:

```
data_files/*
```

I get the following error when I try to checkout:

```
error: Sparse checkout leaves no entry on working directory
```

However, when I change the contents to the following:

```
common_core/*
```

It works fine.  If I add both of them, I only get the common_core showing up.  Why does it work for some directories and not others.

Comment: Presumably all of this is because there are no files named `data_files/*` in the commit you are asking Git to check out.  Check the spelling—is it perhaps `data-files` or `Data_files` or some other such variant?

Comment: I've checked several times and I actually was copying and pasting to make absolutely sure.  I actually was about to post that I got this resolved by remove the * from the directory name.

Comment: Interesting. These are supposed to be glob patterns... aha, perhaps that's it: they *are* glob patterns and `data_files/foo/bar` does not match `data_files/*` but rather `data_files/*/*`, or equivalently, `data_files/**`.

Comment: If that were the case, wouldn't it at least see that data_files/foo matches and keep that and ignore data_files/foo/bar?

Comment: Maybe. This would be code-path dependent.